# How to launch app in appium from home page

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I have an android , for which i have written , more than 10 test cases.
I want to login my application only once than i want to launch my application before every test from application home page or first page .

let me know , how can we achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Perform your first step with logging, then just issue `driver.resetApp()` after each test (you can issue it inside `@BeforeTest` annotation, it depends on your test framework), if your application is able to save the state, you won't have to login again.

Comment: As of now i have written driver.launchApp inside @BeforeTest.

Comment: how is driver.launchApp() and driver.resetapp() is different

Comment: Please refer to the [docs](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/app/reset-app/) to know what is the difference

Answer (score 0):

I have never try that but below method might be helpful for you. 
Note: Dont quit the driver after first test

```
 @BeforeTest
 public void before()
 {
     if (driver == null)
     {
         // initialize the driver  
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) You can achieve by setting DesiredCapabilty. Kindly add the below code into your DesiredCapabilty.

```
// just start Application. For example, Once you have a login and close the application and you execute again then it will open from the home page.
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, false);
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
```

2.) Also you can use resetApp() function. It will close the app and then reopens

```
driver.resetApp();
```